# Multi-level: cross level interaction model

Tags: multilevel-analysis

I have a question regarding multi-level analysis. I follow the paper of Agunis & Culpepper (2013) on best practices in multi-level modelling. In the last step when I put interaction term of L1 and L2 variable, the slope variance becomes insignificant. so I cannot model both random intercept and random slope model when I have the interaction term in the model. Intuitively it sounds to me possible: I put interaction term and take away the variance coming from the fact that slopes differ across teams. Should I then report the data with only random intercept?

Comment: Are you referring to: Agunis, Gottfriedson, & Culpeper (2013), Best-Practice Recommendations for Estimating Cross-Level Interaction Effects Using Multilevel Modeling. Journal of Management September 2013 vol. 39 no. 6 1490-1528?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going by Snijders and Bosker 1999. You already seem to have the answer: The cross-level interaction should explain some of the slope variance. Presumably, the model with the interaction should have a lower slope variance (or, in your case, none) and fit better. Unless there is a good reason not to include the interaction, it seems that by including the cross-level interaction, you are achieving a fundamental goal of modeling.